# I'm trying to get a custom head on an armor stand for my Minecraft map but I cant seem to get it to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to get this code to work for a while but it just wont work. It keeps telling me I'm missing a `"}"` but I've checked so many times but cant seem to find a missing one. Its supposed to be a posed armor stand that i want a certain way but this is the only thing giving me difficulties.

```
/give @p armor_stand{EntityTag:{CustomNameVisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ShowArms:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,Pose:{Body:[3f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[311f,1f,0f],RightArm:[313f,345f,14f],RightLeg:[349f,0f,0f],Head:[24f,0f,0f]},DisabledSlots:4144959,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:book",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:feather",Count:1b}],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510},Unbreakable:1b}},{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510}}},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510}}},{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:"{Id:[I;595495383,-365868612,-1093421993,-927957781],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZGUwNmQxMjgyOWIyOTE3YjE2NjY0YzgxYTJmYmMwOTAzNGJlNGE1YTQyNmU5ZjFiNmFkNTEzNjQwNTcxMWIyYSJ9fX0="}]}}"}}],CustomName:'{"text":"James","color":"white","bold":true}'}} 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SkullOwner` is not a string and so should not be inside quotes:

```
/give @p armor_stand{EntityTag:{CustomNameVisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ShowArms:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,Pose:{Body:[3f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[311f,1f,0f],RightArm:[313f,345f,14f],RightLeg:[349f,0f,0f],Head:[24f,0f,0f]},DisabledSlots:4144959,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:book",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:feather",Count:1b}],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:leather_boots",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510},Unbreakable:1b}},{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510}}},{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{display:{color:9045510}}},{id:"minecraft:player_head",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:[I;595495383,-365868612,-1093421993,-927957781],Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZGUwNmQxMjgyOWIyOTE3YjE2NjY0YzgxYTJmYmMwOTAzNGJlNGE1YTQyNmU5ZjFiNmFkNTEzNjQwNTcxMWIyYSJ9fX0="}]}}}}],CustomName:'{"text":"James","color":"white","bold":true}'}} 1
```